# How to add a new field to an existing google contact in .NET

Tags: .net, api, contacts, shared, insert-update

Goodmorning,

I write this post because i have a problem using the google api.

Google Api Documentation relase the code below for update a contact in .NET:
(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts)

---

```
public static Contact UpdateContactName(ContactsRequest cr, Uri contactURL)
{
  // First, retrieve the contact to update.
  Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURL);
  contact.Name.FullName = "New Name";
  contact.Name.GivenName = "New";
  contact.Name.FamilyName = "Name";
  try
  {
    Contact updatedContact = cr.Update(contact);
    Console.WriteLine("Updated: " + updatedEntry.Updated.ToString())
    return updatedContact;
  }
  catch (GDataVersionConflictException e)
  {
    // Etags mismatch: handle the exception.
  }
  return null;
}
```

---

Well in this example we find a google contact in directory and update the name attribute of the contact.
I tested the code and it's works fine.

However if i want to add a new phone number field and not modify an existing one, How i can do that?

I tried in many ways but i'm not able to do that.

Thanks to all in advance.

Best Regard,
Alessio.